# How do I configure Java security settings, etc?

Tags: java

I have installed JDK 7, but how do I configure settings like security, etc?

On Windows, I can set up JDK 7 from Control Panel -> Java.

Comment: Maybe it have some configuration files, you can find them by `dpkg -L openjdk-7-jre`. This command list all files installed by that package.

Comment: Is [policytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/policytool.html) helpful?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The name of the control panel is different depending on whether you are using the Oracle JDK or OpenJDK.

Search for "control panel" in the dash. If you're using the Oracle JDK, you'll see the *Oracle Java 7 Plugin Control Panel*. If you're using OpenJDK, you'll see the *Iced Tea Web Control Panel*.

Comment: If you use Oracle Java you can run the control panel from jcontrol under the installation path, if you prefer to use a terminal

Answer (score 5):

Search for "java" in dash and it will show java control panel. Images from what it shows when started:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: No,I couldn't find out this in dash command, what Java Packages I had installed are:- 
icedtea-7-jre-jamvm:amd64, 
openjdk-7-jdk:amd64,
openjdk-7-jre:amd64,
openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64

Answer (score 5):

To configure certificates in Java control panel for OpenJDK or IcedTea-Web use the command:

```
javaws -viewer
```

Comment: Also works for Oracle Java

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu/mate, you have to configure the IcedTea Web control panel.

```
System -> Preferences -> IcedTea Web control panel
```

then you can adjust the security level as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: This program can also be invoked by 'itweb-settings' at terminal

Answer (score 0):

Just in case others are using [webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html) to install the Oracle JDKs, Dash didn't show the Java Control Panel (just the iced tea version).

I ended up having to run the Java Control Panel directly from the command line via `/usr/bin/ControlPanel` - their install scripts use `update-alternatives` to point there.